# How do I increment a UUID gatling feeder

Tags: scala, gatling

I am new to gatling and scala, so this is definitely a n00b question but I am struggling to figure this out. I found this great blog post to be able to use a UUID feeder http://www.andrewgorton.uk/blog/gatling-uuid-feeder/

```
object UuidFeeder {
    val feeder = new Feeder[String] {
        override def hasNext = true

        override def next: Map[String, String] = {
            Map("uuid" -> UUID.randomUUID.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

This works great, my issue is that I can't figure out how to get a new value, when I put it into a loop.

I am using it like this -

```
val scn = scenario("Test Scenario")
  .feed(UuidFeeder.feeder)
    .exec(http("get stuff")
                .post("/stuff")
                .body(StringBody(
                """{
                   "uuid": "${uuid}",
                }""")).asJSON
                .check(status.is(201)))
```

If I use ${uuid} in a subsequent test, it will be the same value. How do I get a new value for the next call?

Comment: where do you call UuidFeeder.feeder?   can you show us what is before the exec?

Comment: I added it. it is inside the scenario

Comment: I get a "not found: type Feeder" error relating to this piece of code.
new Feeder[String]
Presumably, I need to import something, but cannot for the life of me find out what.

Comment: I found it! :)
import io.gatling.core.feeder._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me and should generate different UUIDs for each virtual user every time they reach the feed action.

Comment: Seems like this was due to my misunderstanding of how feeds worked, i just needed to call the feed before i used it again it seems. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer using the [Iterator.continually](http://gatling.io/docs/2.2/session/feeder/#feeders) helper instead like so:

```
object UuidFeeder {
    val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("uuid" -> java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString()))
}
```

usage would be the same as before.. hope it helps :)

```
// Usage
//
// scenario("My Scenario")
//      .feed(UuidFeeder.feeder)
//      .exec(http("MyCall"))
//    ...// rest of code
```

Comment: Why the down vote.. if I've done something wrong at least let me know..